# Render Razor View to string in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I use [RazorEngine](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine) for parsing of templates in my MVC 6 project like this:

```
Engine.Razor.RunCompile(File.ReadAllText(fullTemplateFilePath), templateName, null, model);
```

It works fine for the beta 6. It does not work after upgrading to beta 7 with the error:

> MissingMethodException: Method not found: "Void Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.CodeGenerators.GeneratedClassContext.set_ResolveUrlMethodName(System.String)".
>       in RazorEngine.Compilation.CompilerServiceBase.CreateHost(Type templateType, Type modelType, String className)

This is global.json:

```
{
  "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "runtime": "clr",
    "architecture": "x64"
  }
}
```

This is project.json:

```
...
"dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta7",
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Facebook": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Google": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Twitter": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Abstractions": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-beta7",
    "RazorEngine": "4.2.2-beta1"
  },
...
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { }
  },
...
```

My template is:

```html
@model dynamic
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Registration</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>
    Hello, @Model
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone have similar problems?
There is another way to parse templates in MVC 6?

Comment: I didn't read the question, but voting up for the answer :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

#### UPDATE July, 2016

Working fine on the following versions `1.0.0`, `RC2`

---

Who's targeting aspnetcore RC2, this snippet might help you:

- Create a separate Service, so you can use it either if you are not in a controller context, e.g. from a command line or on a queue runner, etc ...
- Register this service in your IoC container in the `Startup` class

https://gist.github.com/ahmad-moussawi/1643d703c11699a6a4046e57247b4d09

## Usage

```
// using a Model
string html = view.Render("Emails/Test", new Product("Apple"));

// using a Dictionary<string, object>
var viewData = new Dictionary<string, object>();
viewData["Name"] = "123456";

string html = view.Render("Emails/Test", viewData);
```

#### Notes

Links in Razor are rendered as **relative** URL, so this will not work on external views (like emails, etc ...).

As for now am generating the link on the controller and pass it to the view through the ViewModel.

#### Credit

The source is extracted from (Thanks To @pholly): https://github.com/aspnet/Entropy/blob/dev/samples/Mvc.RenderViewToString/RazorViewToStringRenderer.cs)

Comment: Gist is exactly same code as https://github.com/aspnet/Entropy/blob/dev/samples/Mvc.RenderViewToString/RazorViewToStringRenderer.cs which was created because of https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/3091

Comment: I'm having trouble getting this to work if I use a link taghelper in the view: `<a asp-controller="Whatever" asp-action="DoSomething" asp-route-thingy="ThingyValue">link text</a>`.

Comment: @BenCollins, I am assuming, you are getting a wrong URL (relative URL), which doesn't work on external links like emails, is that right ?

Comment: @Ahmad no, the issue was the the link taghelper needed more context in order to work.  The link taghelper depends on `UrlHelper`, and `UrlHelper` needs real routedata or it throws an exception.  Fortunately for me I am doing this within an MVC app, so I can just use `IHttpContextAccessor` to build an `ActionContext` with real values

Comment: Yes I think this was my problem too, cz I've needed to add an extension method *AbsoluteAction* to the `IUrlHelper`, happy that you found a solution:)

Comment: If anyone is having a trouble where you cannot find the views make sure that in project.json you have 

`"copyToOutput": {
  "include": "Views"
  }`

Answer (score 22):

I found this thread which discusses it: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/3091

Someone in the thread created a sample service here: https://github.com/aspnet/Entropy/blob/dev/samples/Mvc.RenderViewToString/RazorViewToStringRenderer.cs

After trial and error I was able to trim the service down so it only needs a valid `HttpContext` and a `ViewEngine` and I added an overload that doesn't require a model. Views are relative to your application root (they don't have to live in a `Views` folder).

You will need to register the service in `Startup.cs` and also register `HttpContextAccessor`:

```cs
//Startup.cs ConfigureServices()
services.AddTransient<ViewRenderService>();
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures;
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace LibraryApi.Services
{
    public class ViewRenderService
    {
        IRazorViewEngine _viewEngine;
        IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

        public ViewRenderService(IRazorViewEngine viewEngine, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            _viewEngine = viewEngine;
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }

        public string Render(string viewPath)
        {
            return Render(viewPath, string.Empty);
        }

        public string Render<TModel>(string viewPath, TModel model)
        {
            var viewEngineResult = _viewEngine.GetView("~/", viewPath, false);

            if (!viewEngineResult.Success)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"Couldn't find view {viewPath}");
            }

            var view = viewEngineResult.View;

            using (var output = new StringWriter())
            {
                var viewContext = new ViewContext();
                viewContext.HttpContext = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
                viewContext.ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary<TModel>(new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(), new ModelStateDictionary())
                { Model = model };
                viewContext.Writer = output;

                view.RenderAsync(viewContext).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

                return output.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using LibraryApi.Services;
using System.Dynamic;

namespace LibraryApi.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ValuesController : Controller
    {
        ILogger<ValuesController> _logger;
        ViewRenderService _viewRender;
        public ValuesController(ILogger<ValuesController> logger, ViewRenderService viewRender)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _viewRender = viewRender;
        }

        // GET api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public string Get()
        {
            //ViewModel is of type dynamic - just for testing
            dynamic x = new ExpandoObject();
            x.Test = "Yes";
            var viewWithViewModel = _viewRender.Render("eNotify/Confirm.cshtml", x);
            var viewWithoutViewModel = _viewRender.Render("MyFeature/Test.cshtml");
            return viewWithViewModel + viewWithoutViewModel;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You - Works great with ASP.NET Core 1.0.1. Love the general/service approach :)

Comment: Thanks @pholly, this works great with Core 1.1 as well. Its a really nice solution for the problem. Any thoughts on what it would take for _ViewImports.cshtml, _ViewStart.cshtml and _Layout.cshtml to be taken into account, including the RenderBody and RenderSection commands used in _Layout.cshtml? I tried placing them in the same folder as the view being loaded, but they weren't used, at least based on the resulting output.

Comment: @TommyBaggett I based the code on this: https://github.com/aspnet/Entropy/blob/dev/samples/Mvc.RenderViewToString/RazorViewToStringRenderer.cs so I can't take the credit :) I didn't realize `_Layout.cshtml` and such wouldn't be used - perhaps an `ActionContext` is needed after all for those to be loaded? Try the service I linked to and see if it works. It uses an `ActionContext`.

Comment: Thanks @pholly, I gave that one a try and had issues with it finding my views. I gave the RazorLight engine a try (https://github.com/toddams/RazorLight) as suggested in another answer below. Its working great.

Comment: With ASP.NET Core 1.1.0 I was having an issue that went away when I started using the version here: https://github.com/aspnet/Entropy/blob/dev/samples/Mvc.RenderViewToString/RazorViewToStringRenderer.cs. Before adopting the approach in the sample, the call stack for my error was very similar to this one: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/5505

Comment: Thank you Richard Logwood. I had the same issue - trying to use my views as email content - and went ahead to use the example at your link.

Comment: Is there any reason why you've registered `IHttpContextAccessor` as a singleton?

Comment: Is there any way to get this to render javascript on the client? For example this does not render: <div id="Test"></div> and document.getElementById("Test").innerHTML = "whatever". The javascript never executes.

Answer (score 15):

In the past, I’ve used the `RazorEngine` inside a Class Library because my goal was to render templates from within this Class Library.

From my understanding, you seem to be inside an MVC 6.0 project so why not use a `RenderPartialViewToString()` method without having to add the dependency on the `RazorEngine`?

Keep in mind, I'm only asking because I'm curious.

For example purposes, from within VS2015, I created a new ASP.NET Web Application and selected the Web Application template from the ASP.NET 5 Preview Templates.

Inside the `ViewModels` folder, I created a `PersonViewModel`:

```cs
public class PersonViewModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("{0} {1}", this.FirstName, this.LastName);
        }
    } 
}
```

I then created a new `BaseController` and added a `RenderPartialViewToString()` method:

```cs
public string RenderPartialViewToString(string viewName, object model)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
        viewName = ActionContext.ActionDescriptor.Name;

    ViewData.Model = model;

    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        var engine = Resolver.GetService(typeof(ICompositeViewEngine)) as ICompositeViewEngine;
        ViewEngineResult viewResult = engine.FindPartialView(ActionContext, viewName);

        ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(ActionContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw,new HtmlHelperOptions());

        var t = viewResult.View.RenderAsync(viewContext);
        t.Wait();

        return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
    }
}
```

Credit goes to @DavidG for his [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31905624/where-are-the-controllercontext-and-viewengines-properties-in-mvc-6-controller)

Inside the `Views-->Shared` folder, I created a new **Templates** folder in which I’ve added a simple `RegistrationTemplate.cshtml` View **strongly typed** to my `PersonViewModel` like so:

```html
@model MyWebProject.ViewModels.PersonViewModel
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Registration</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        Hello, @Model.FullName
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

The last step is to make my `Controller` inherit from my `BaseController`

```cs
public class MyController : BaseController
```

And create something like:

```cs
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new PersonViewModel();
    model.FirstName = "Frank";
    model.LastName = "Underwood";
    var emailbody = base.RenderPartialViewToString("Templates/RegistrationTemplate", model);

    return View();
}
```

Of course, the example above is useless since I do nothing with the variable `emailbody` but the idea is to show how it’s used.

At this point, I could've(for example), invoke an `EmailService` and pass the `emailbody`:

```cs
_emailService.SendEmailAsync("test@test.com", "registration", emailbody);
```

I'm not sure if this is suitable alternative for your current task.

Comment: How to do the same inside the Class Library? You do not have a ActionContext there...

Comment: The example above shows how to render a View to String. The example lives inside an asp.net MVC application where all the dependencies are already present. If you plan on using something similar but within a Class Library, the above approach may not be the best one as you won’t have all the necessary dependencies and what not...For that, you might want to try a different approach like this one: http://www.strathweb.com/2016/01/re-using-external-view-components-in-asp-net-5-asp-net-mvc-6/

Answer (score 13):

Today I've finished with my library that can solve your problem. You can use it out of ASP.NET as it has no dependencies on it

Example:

```
string content = "Hello @Model.Name. Welcome to @Model.Title repository";

var model = new
{
  Name = "John Doe",
  Title = "RazorLight"
};

var engine = new RazorLightEngine();
string result = engine.ParseString(content, model);

//Output: Hello John Doe, Welcome to RazorLight repository
```

More: https://github.com/toddams/RazorLight

Comment: Thanks for making your RazorLight library available. Some of the other solutions offered here work as long as you're parsing a single view file. I switched to your library when I needed support for _ViewStart and _Layout files being taken into account. Your lib is working great for my needs.

Comment: I had a hard time getting other solutions to work. But this worked great!!

Comment: @toddams can you help me with issue I opened, we are trying to use the library for genrating dynamic templates from dynamic models issue `https://github.com/toddams/RazorLight/issues/158`

Comment: Great solution. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

To improve on @vlince answer (that wasn't working out of the box for me), here is what I did :

1- Create a base controller that your other controller will inherit

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using System.IO;

namespace YourNameSpace
{
    public class BaseController : Controller
    {
        protected ICompositeViewEngine viewEngine;

        public BaseController(ICompositeViewEngine viewEngine)
        {
            this.viewEngine = viewEngine;
        }

        protected string RenderViewAsString(object model, string viewName = null)
        {
            viewName = viewName ?? ControllerContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;
            ViewData.Model = model;

            using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                IView view = viewEngine.FindView(ControllerContext, viewName, true).View;
                ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, view, ViewData, TempData, sw, new HtmlHelperOptions());

                view.RenderAsync(viewContext).Wait();

                return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2- Inherit the base controller and call the method

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines;

namespace YourNameSpace
{
    public class YourController : BaseController
    {
        public YourController(ICompositeViewEngine viewEngine) : base(viewEngine) { }

        public string Index(int? id)
        {
            var model = new MyModel { Name = "My Name" };

            return RenderViewAsString(model);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You - Works great with ASP.NET Core 1.0.1

Comment: Should TutorialController actually be YourController in the example? Otherwise, thanks a bunch for this idea. I had forgotten this technique, more or less, from my old ASP.NET form days with the use of BaseForm :)

Answer (score 3):

`ResolveUrlMethodName` was removed. Therefore in your `CreateHost` [here](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine/blob/590b79cfb6253d6aa5e83863994ce12ae6178a34/src/source/RazorEngine.Core/Compilation/CompilerServiceBase.cs#L255) you're trying to set a property that doesn't exist :).

We decided to move `~/` handling from core Razor into a `TagHelper` implemented in the `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Razor` assembly. Here's the [commit](https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/commit/48a6b567d6d2194ce390599c37ef1e1b7c9c5a9e) to the bits that removed the method.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! I'll have a view of it in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Extension method for converting partial views to string response.

```
public static class PartialViewToString
{
    public static async Task<string> ToString(this PartialViewResult partialView, ActionContext actionContext)
    {
        using(var writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            var services = actionContext.HttpContext.RequestServices;
            var executor = services.GetRequiredService<PartialViewResultExecutor>();
            var view = executor.FindView(actionContext, partialView).View;
            var viewContext = new ViewContext(actionContext, view, partialView.ViewData, partialView.TempData, writer, new HtmlHelperOptions());
            await view.RenderAsync(viewContext);
            return writer.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Usage in your controller actions.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    return await PartialView().ToString(ControllerContext)
}
```

.NET 5 Implementation

```
public static async Task<string> ViewToString(this PartialViewResult partialView, Controller controller)
    {
        using (var writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            var services = controller.ControllerContext.HttpContext.RequestServices;
            var viewEngine = services.GetService(typeof(ICompositeViewEngine)) as ICompositeViewEngine;
            var viewName = partialView.ViewName ?? controller.ControllerContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;
            var view = viewEngine.FindView(controller.ControllerContext, viewName, false).View;
            var viewContext = new ViewContext(controller.ControllerContext, view, partialView.ViewData, partialView.TempData, writer, new HtmlHelperOptions());
            await view.RenderAsync(viewContext);
            return writer.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to work on .NET 5 anymore. I couldn't figure out how to get the PartialViewResultExecutor to be registered. :(
`No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.PartialViewResultExecutor' has been registered.`

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution using just ASP.NET Core, no external libraries, and no reflection can be found here: https://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/getting-html-for-a-viewresult-in-asp-net-core. It just requires a `ViewResult` and an `HttpContext`.

The idea is to pick up a `ViewResult` and call some method, say, `ToHtml`, to get the rendered output. This method can look like this:

```cs
public static class ViewResultExtensions {
    public static string ToHtml(this ViewResult result, HttpContext httpContext) {            
        var feature = httpContext.Features.Get<IRoutingFeature>();
        var routeData = feature.RouteData;
        var viewName = result.ViewName ?? routeData.Values["action"] as string;
        var actionContext = new ActionContext(httpContext, routeData, new ControllerActionDescriptor());
        var options = httpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IOptions<MvcViewOptions>>();
        var htmlHelperOptions = options.Value.HtmlHelperOptions;
        var viewEngineResult = result.ViewEngine?.FindView(actionContext, viewName, true) ?? options.Value.ViewEngines.Select(x => x.FindView(actionContext, viewName, true)).FirstOrDefault(x => x != null);
        var view = viewEngineResult.View;
        var builder = new StringBuilder();

        using (var output = new StringWriter(builder)) {
            var viewContext = new ViewContext(actionContext, view, result.ViewData, result.TempData, output, htmlHelperOptions);

            view
                .RenderAsync(viewContext)
                .GetAwaiter()
                .GetResult();
        }
        return builder.ToString();
    }
}
```

To use it, just do:

```cs
var view = this.View(“ViewName”);
var html = view.ToHtml();
```