# Render view as string in MVC 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

After a long search for a solution to this problem, I only found MVC5 and outdated solutions.

Now that we are in asp.net 5 beta 7, there are any way to render a view to a string variable ?

I need to render a view to show it in a bootbox javascript control (like a modal windows).

The MVC 5 solutions does not work in version 6 because there is no "ViewEngine" class in there. Look:

[image]

and even the Razor object can´t be found:

[image]

Comment: You'll have a better chance to get the dupe mark removed if you can update to explain why the known MVC5 options aren't possible in MVC6

Comment: You're likely missing references - maybe `Microsoft.Aspnet.Mvc.ViewFeatures` and `Microsoft.Aspnet.Mvc.Razor`. You can have a dig around the [github repo](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc) to find exactly what you want, including checking the unit tests to see what they reference.

Comment: Hi @Jon, are you sure you using mvc 6 ? A lot of things changes.

Comment: @paulo Yep - but its all beta, so you'll need to hunt around a little for it. According to the page linked, the `Razor.Parse` method uses a `RazorEngine` library which looks like it's being updated for Razor4 and Roslyn.

Comment: So basically your question is _"Which references and usings do I need to make this code work"_? You also **really** don't need to render a view to string, you can make an AJAX request to get the popup's contents.

Comment: why dont you just use a partial view ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this approach (see `RenderPartialViewToString`): 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32577016/2631076

Comment: Finally a solution that works.