# Razor Engine not working in ASP.net 5 MVC 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, templates, razor, asp.net-core, razorengine

I am trying to migrate some existing code from MVC5 to MVC6 and I am having difficulty with this particular code:

```
 Engine.Razor.RunCompile(File.ReadAllText(emailTemplatePath), "emailTemplateKey", typeof (EmailViewModel), emailViewModel);
```

I am receiving the following runtime error:

```
MissingMethodException: Method not found: "Void Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.CodeGenerators.GeneratedClassContext.set_ResolveUrlMethodName(System.String)". in RazorEngine.Compilation.CompilerServiceBase.CreateHost(Type templateType, Type modelType, String className)
```

The original code I was using in MVC5 was taken from [here](http://mehdi.me/generating-html-emails-with-razorengine-introduction/). If there is no way of converting the above code to work with MVC6 what is another elegant way of doing email templates?

Comment: Do not mention other posts that describe a problem similar to yours, without explaining your situation. Also post your code, and the error messages you get. Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then edit your question

Comment: you want to migrate from mvc5 to mvc6 or create a email template

Answer (score 2):

Apparently there has been a change in [`GeneratedClassContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.razor.generator%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) class - the property `ResolveUrlMethodName` does not exist anymore, hence the `MissingMethodException`. Looks like [`ParserContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.razor.parser.parsercontext%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) class has changed too, since accessing `OnError` event handler throws the same exception.

In fact it is the setter of the missing property missing (pardon the expression!), which, being a method, causes the exception. Absolutely accurate but somewhat misleading, unless you recall this.

Quite a similar question (and a good answer with *alternative solution*!) here: [RazorEngine and MVC 6 beta 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32558941/razorengine-and-mvc-6-beta-7).