# Servicestack migration to core, fallback router and HandlerFactoryPath

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, servicestack

Im migrating my code to a core application.

So far so good. i got it all running, but there is one problem.

I had a ui (with razor) and using the `CatchAllHandlers`. And for the api i used `HandlerFactoryPath` to prefix the urls.

Now i have 2 problems:

- It seems `CatchAllHandlers` isn't used?
- Route is only processed if route starts with HandlerFactoryPath?

The second issue is fixable but how would i go around the first one?

Do i make my own middle-ware or does servicestack support other ways of doing this?

Comment: When i remove the HandlerFactoryPath the catchall routing seems to work

Comment: Im trying to render a partial now using: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39400153/1275832 (inside a subclass of ss.mvc.viewPage<T>. but this keeps throwing me errosr now

Answer (score 1):

`CatchAllHandlers` are executed in .NET Core, it's also what ServiceStack's [new MVC RazorFormat uses to process Content Pages](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/5c132791e94190db606700971b9070545e295c3a/src/ServiceStack.Mvc/RazorFormat.cs#L65).

Specifying a `HandlerFactoryPath`, e.g:

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig {
    HandlerFactoryPath = "api"
});
```

Tells ServiceStack that you only want to listen to requests from the `/api` path info. All other requests are passed through ServiceStack who calls the next module in .NET Core pipeline as per .NET Core's convention when it's not configured to handle a route.

Not sure if it's relevant to your solution but in ServiceStack .NET Core you can register a [ServiceStack Handler in .NET Core module pipeline](http://docs.servicestack.net/netcore#register-servicestack-httphandlers-as-net-core-modules) so you could for instance return a `/default.cshtml` Content Razor Page for each request that's not handled by ServiceStack, by registering it after ServiceStack:

```
app.UseServiceStack(new AppHost());

app.Use(new RazorHandler("/default"));
```