# undefined is not assigned to ComponentFactory<any> 'DynamicComponent'

Tags: angular, typescript

In search of rendering MVC View in to angular 2 end up with this [directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41473511/how-to-render-asp-net-mvc-view-into-angular-2)

```
export function createComponentFactory(compiler: Compiler, metadata: Component): Promise<ComponentFactory<any>> {
  const cmpClass = class DynamicComponent {};
  const decoratedCmp = Component(metadata)(cmpClass);

  @NgModule({ imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule], declarations: [decoratedCmp] })
  class DynamicHtmlModule { }

  return compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(DynamicHtmlModule)
    .then((moduleWithComponentFactory: ModuleWithComponentFactories<any>) => {
      return moduleWithComponentFactory.componentFactories.find(x => x.componentType === decoratedCmp);
    });
}
```

All working fine my `View` rendering as I wanted but after few seconds this Error pops.

[image]

my Component Code:

```
 import {
    Component,
    Directive,
    NgModule,
    Input,
    ViewContainerRef,
    Compiler,
    ComponentFactory,
    ModuleWithComponentFactories,
    ComponentRef,
    ReflectiveInjector, OnInit, OnDestroy, Type
} from '@angular/core';

import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Http } from "@angular/http";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

export function createComponentFactory(compiler: Compiler, metadata: Component): Promise<ComponentFactory<any>> {   
    const cmpClass = class DynamicComponent { };
    const decoratedCmp = Component(metadata)(cmpClass);

    @NgModule({ imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule], declarations: [decoratedCmp] })
    class DynamicHtmlModule { }

    return compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(DynamicHtmlModule)
        .then((moduleWithComponentFactory: ModuleWithComponentFactories<any>) => {
            return moduleWithComponentFactory.componentFactories.find(x => x.componentType === decoratedCmp);
        });
}

@Directive({ selector: 'mvc-partial' })
export class RenderingViewDynamic implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    html: string = '<p></p>';
    @Input() url: string;
    cmpRef: ComponentRef<any>;

    constructor(private vcRef: ViewContainerRef, private compiler: Compiler, private http: Http) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.http.get(this.url)
            .map(res => res.text())
            .subscribe(
            (html) => {
                this.html = html;
                if (!html) return;

                if (this.cmpRef) {
                    this.cmpRef.destroy();
                }

                const compMetadata = new Component({
                    selector: 'dynamic-html',
                    template: this.html,
                });

                createComponentFactory(this.compiler, compMetadata)
                    .then(factory => {
                        const injector = ReflectiveInjector.fromResolvedProviders([], this.vcRef.parentInjector);
                        this.cmpRef = this.vcRef.createComponent(factory, 0, injector, []);
                    });
            },
            err => console.log(err),
            () => console.log('MvcPartial complete')
            );

    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        if (this.cmpRef) {
            this.cmpRef.destroy();
        }
    }
}
```

How could I over come this?

Comment: Please add code from `RenderingViewDynamic.component.ts`

Comment: updated @yurzui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you define a method that returns `Promise<ComponentFactory<any>>`, however inside the method you use `find` function which can return `undefined`:

> The find() method returns the value of the first element in the array
>   that satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise **undefined** is
>   returned.

So that is what TS complains about. Just modify the method call:

```
createComponentFactory(...): `Promise<ComponentFactory<any>> | Promise<undefined>` { ... }
```

Same thing here:

```
this.cmpRef = this.vcRef.createComponent(factory, 0, injector, []);
                    });
```

`createComponent` can only take `ComponentFactory<C>` but with your implementation it's possible that `undefined` can be passed. Maybe add a check that factory exists or if you're sure that it will never be undefined use [non-null](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#non-null-assertion-operator) assertion operator.

Comment: @MaximKorestskyi  what you guess is right but  your suggestion didn't resolve my issue same error occurs. Added my total code once check.

Comment: _but with your implementation it's possible that `undefined` can be passed_.
Totally agreed . 
_Maybe add a check that factory exists_ what you mean ?

Comment: factory having value, not undefined.

Comment: @k11k2, `if (factory) { this.vcRef.createComponent( ....) }`. What do you expect to happen if you pass `undefined` into `createComponent`?

Comment: target would be rendering my component with out exception so override that undefined make it smooth process.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152491/discussion-between-k11k2-and-maxim-koretskyi).