# Loading of ajax result in layout

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core

In the Asp.NET core's layout page, I'm trying to load the result of an AJAX post. Status is OK but comes as an error:

_Layout.cshtml

```
<div id="MainContentDiv">
  @RenderBody()
</div>
```

```js
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/Something/LoadView',
  dataType: 'json',
  contentType: 'application/json',
  data: JSON.stringify({ ... }),
  error: function (result) {
    console.log("error");
    console.log(result);
  },
  success: function (result) {
    $("#MainContentDiv").html(result);
  }
```

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LoadView([FromBody] NodeData model)
{
  string action= "Index";
  switch(model.NodeType)
  {
    case StringConstants.something:
      action = "GData";
      break;
    // ...
  }  
  return RedirectToAction(action, "Some", model);
}

public PartialViewResult GData(NodeData model)
{
  // ... 
  return PartialView("_GroupsData", group);
}
```

Response

[image]

Comment: Are you saying that the `error` handler is being executed despite the response status code being `200`?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes, that's right.

Comment: I doubt that is the case, otherwise it's a *massive* bug in jQuery. Are you sure you're seeing the response of the same AJAX call? Under what event are you making this AJAX request?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes, I've cross-checked.

Comment: Your method return ActionResult,please change return type, or change AJAX method

Comment: @ahmeticat Ajax calls a method which calls another method as I've shown in the code. Please let me know what has to be changed.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan On the treeview node selected event, I am making this Ajax request.

Comment: What does the responseText say?

Comment: @TSmith I'm able to get the partial view's HTML in the responseText

Comment: @TSmith I'm able to get the partial view's HTML in the responseText

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dataType` is you telling jQuery what kind of response to expect.

Since you return html instead of json result from server,try to remove the `dataType: 'json'` in your ajax directly. Refer to [ajax dataType](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/Something/LoadView',
  //dataType: 'json',
  contentType: 'application/json',
  data: JSON.stringify({ ... }),
  error: function (result) {
    console.log("error");
    console.log(result);
  },
  success: function (result) {
    $("#MainContentDiv").html(result);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, create the function which parse `ActionResult` to `string`

```
public string RenderRazorViewToString(string viewName, object model)
{
  ViewData.Model = model;
  using (var sw = new StringWriter())
  {
    var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext,
                                                             viewName);
    var viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View,
                                 ViewData, TempData, sw);
    viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
    viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(ControllerContext, viewResult.View);
    return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
  }
}
```

and  `return Json(RenderRazorViewToString(action,model), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)`

instead of  `return RedirectToAction(action, "Some", model)`

**UPDATE** : update for .NET Core

Just change `return RedirectToAction(action, "Some", model)` to `view.Render("Some/"+action, model)`;

Comment: I'm on Asp.NET core 2.2 and I'm not able to resolve namespace issues.

Comment: Found the core version at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32558941/render-razor-view-to-string-in-asp-net-core

Comment: would be great if you could edit your answer accordingly.

Comment: unfortunately, I couldn't get even the core version working.