# How to Apply filter to list without resetting control values after search button click?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a List of Persons and  filtration controls in a form with search button. When search button is clicked list populated with filtered data but search controls also loose their selected values. I'm not sure this is the best way to do this.

I have tried splitting view into partial and main view i.e. List of Persons is in Partial view and Filtration Controls are in main view.

List should be filtered without loosing search controls values. What should be the best practice to accomplish this task? Sample Image >> [list with filtration controls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kk8Fr.png)

Comment: Can you produce a minimal, working sample that shows the problem and post the code? Don't post all your current code, make an example with a single filter and the search button code.

Comment: Maybe your view has been refreshed when you return the View.You could use ajax and partial view.When you click the the button, send a ajax request to action,and return a partail view, render this response in your view use `html(result)`.Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55397795/loading-of-ajax-result-in-layout/55411665#55411665

Comment: @XingZou It could be a little twisty for newbies to use ajax and render the result on client side. It's better to use MVC's default stuff to achieve that for better security and it's easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use ViewBag to store the data in the controller first, like this:

```
    public ActionResult YourSearchPage()
    {
        //Bind the data to a list here
        List<YourResultType> result = //Get from DB
        return View(result);
    }

    //When the user clicks the "Search" button
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult YourSearchPage(string keyword, int listingType...)
    {
        //Bind the data to a list here
        List<YourResultType> result = //Get from DB
        ViewBag.keyword = keyword;
        ViewBag.listingType = listingType;
        //Filter the list
        return View(result);
    }
```

And on the view, bind the value to the controls like below:

```
<input type="text" id="keyword" class="keyword" value="@ViewBag.keyword" style="width: 80%;"/>
```