# Convert Razor View to string with JavaScript rendering

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, razor

These answers render a Razor view to a string, but do not execute scripts in the rendered HTML:

- [Return View as String in .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40912375/return-view-as-string-in-net-core)
- [Render Razor View to string in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32558941/render-razor-view-to-string-in-asp-net-core/37296765)

Result of rendering a Razor view to a string:

```
<body>
    <div id="Test"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">      
    document.getElementById("Test").innerHTML = "whatever";
    </script>
</body>
```

Ideally the result would instead be:

```
  <body>
    <div id="Test">whatever</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">      
    document.getElementById("Test").innerHTML = "whatever";
    </script>
  </body>
```

Is there any way to get JavaScript to be evaluated when rendering a Razor view on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Razor is, at the end of the day, a string templating engine. It doesn't actually know much about HTML documents, but it's good at evaluating templates.

Razor is ignoring your JavaScript code because:

- It isn't building a Document Object Model (DOM) like a browser does
- It doesn't have a JavaScript interpreter to execute JavaScript code

You would need both of those in order to achieve your ideal result. That's beyond Razor; it's really a job for a full-fledged browser.

I haven't used it myself, but I'd look into the [Puppeteer Sharp](https://github.com/kblok/puppeteer-sharp) library. Using that, or a similar library, you can take any arbitrary HTML + JavaScript, evaluate it like a browser does, and then capture the resulting document to get the output you need.

Comment: @Watson Glad to hear it! 