# How do I render a view to a string in dotnet core

Tags: razor, .net-core

I would like to build emails in dotnet core 1.0 using the Razor engine, but I cannot work out how to do that.

I have created a view model containing the data for the view and I have made a view and run that view in code:

```
var confirm = new ConfirmEmailHtmlViewModel();
confirm.CallbackUrl = callbackUrl;
var message = View("ConfirmEmailHtml", confirm);
```

What I cannot figure out is how to extract a string containing the rendered view from 'message'.

Is this possible and if it is how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I have answered this here: [Where are the ControllerContext and ViewEngines properties in MVC 6 Controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31905624/where-are-the-controllercontext-and-viewengines-properties-in-mvc-6-controller/38451046#38451046)

The original answer on that question was for a pre-release of ASP.NET Core and not the 1.0 release.