# Required dependencies for Resolver or ServiceProvider for using ICompositeViewEngine

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to use ICompositeViewEngine in ASP.NET Core MVC for substituting ViewEngine from System.Web.Mvc since it is no longer available in .NET Core. I am generally trying to migrate a webform from ASP.NET to ASP.NET Core in this project.

I have found the following solution: [Where are the ControllerContext and ViewEngines properties in MVC 6 Controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31905624/where-are-the-controllercontext-and-viewengines-properties-in-mvc-6-controller) and I believe that this may resolve my issue. I have also found a similar engine creation with ServiceProvider in a github question: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/3091

However, I am not sure about what dependencies or frameworks I may be missing as I am very new with .NET. I have the following namespaces:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
```

That I believe might be related to my issue.

My original code is:

```
    public static string RenderPartialToString(Controller controller, string viewName, object model)
    {
        controller.ViewData.Model = model;

        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controller.ControllerContext, viewName);
            ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(controller.ControllerContext, viewResult.View, controller.ViewData, controller.TempData, sw);
            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

            return "document.write('" + sw.GetStringBuilder().Replace('\n', ' ').Replace('\r', ' ').Replace("'","\\'").ToString() + "');";
        }
    }
```

And now I am trying to use either of the following:

```
 var engine = Resolver.GetService(typeof(ICompositeViewEngine)) as ICompositeViewEngine;
 var engine2 = IServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(ICompositeViewEngine)) as ICompositeViewEngine;
```

Am I on the right track to fix this? Is there an easier way to replace System.Web.Mvc ViewEngines in .NET Core? What do I need to fix "**does not exist in the current context**" errors for Resolver and/or ServiceProvider?

Thanks. I hope I was able to follow the question guidelines.

Edit: Please let me know if I should include anything else from my code for this question. I am currently reading about Dependency Injection to understand the situation better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're mostly on the right track. ASP.NET Core got rid of many static objects so you can't do things like `Resolver.GetService`. `Resolver` doesn't exist. Instead, use the [dependency injection](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/dependency-injection.html) system.

If you just need to access `ICompositeViewEngine` from a controller, inject it in the constructor:

```
public MyController(ICompositeViewEngine viewEngine)
{
    // save a reference to viewEngine
}
```

If you want to have a discrete service that handles Razor-to-string rendering, you'll need to register it at startup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // (Other code...)

    services.AddTransient<IViewRenderingService, ViewRenderingService>();

    services.AddMvc();
}
```

The service itself would look like this:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures;

public interface IViewRenderingService
{
    string RenderPartialView(ActionContext context, string name, object model = null);
}

public class ViewRenderingService : IViewRenderingService
{
    private readonly ICompositeViewEngine _viewEngine;
    private readonly ITempDataProvider _tempDataProvider;

    public ViewRenderingService(ICompositeViewEngine viewEngine, ITempDataProvider tempDataProvider)
    {
        _viewEngine = viewEngine;
        _tempDataProvider = tempDataProvider;
    }

    public string RenderPartialView(ActionContext context, string name, object model)
    {
        var viewEngineResult = _viewEngine.FindView(context, name, false);

        if (!viewEngineResult.Success)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Couldn't find view '{0}'", name));
        }

        var view = viewEngineResult.View;

        using (var output = new StringWriter())
        {
            var viewContext = new ViewContext(
                context,
                view,
                new ViewDataDictionary(
                    new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(),
                    new ModelStateDictionary())
                {
                    Model = model
                },
                new TempDataDictionary(
                    context.HttpContext,
                    _tempDataProvider),
                output,
                new HtmlHelperOptions());

            view.RenderAsync(viewContext).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            return output.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

To use it from a controller, inject and call it:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IViewRenderingService _viewRenderingService;

    public HomeController(IViewRenderingService viewRenderingService)
    {
        _viewRenderingService = viewRenderingService;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var result = _viewRenderingService.RenderPartialView(ControllerContext, "PartialViewName", model: null);
        // do something with the string

        return View();
    }
}
```

If you want to use Razor outside of MVC entirely, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38253402/3191599).

Comment: I'm really grateful for your answer but what references/namespaces should I use for these classes/methods?

Comment: @KemalTezerDilsiz Added the namespaces to the example service code. Does that help?

Comment: The issue is that I am using ViewEngine in a public static class. It is called Utils and has two methods, RenderPartialToString being one the one that I am trying to modify. If it wasn't a static constructor, I am sure this would work. Any suggestions? Should I try to restructure my project?

Comment: @KemalTezerDilsiz Yes, I think you should restructure that part of your project. Having a static class referenced by your web code is considered an antipattern for ASP.NET Core. Where do you call RenderPartialToString? From controllers?

Comment: Yes, I call the RenderPartialToString method from the controllers, could I possibly implement the IViewEngineInterface to my static class for direct reference? (Example use: `return Utils.RenderPartialToString(this, "ContactUsForm", new ContactUs());`) (this being the controller and ContactUs is a Model that stores some values from the generated table)

Comment: You might be able to, but it's a much better approach to get rid of the static class entirely if you can. You can achieve the same functionality using a service class (like the one I demonstrated above), where you inject `IViewRenderingService` into the controller and then call it like `return _viewRenderingService.RenderPartialToString(...)`

Comment: I am getting an error, "An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code // Additional information: The ViewData item that has the key 'InvestorTypeId' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'." in the `view.RenderAsync(viewContext).GetAwaiter().GetResult();` part

Comment: I found the part where it creates a problem: I'll make a new question for it and share the link here in case anybody has the same problem

Comment: Strangely this does not work with Razor Pages - the Model is null in the View. I think the processing in Razor Pages is different than in standard MVC