# How to render a view to html string in asp.net core controller?

Tags: razor, asp.net-core

In my asp.net core 2.0 application, I need to show the details of a payment receipt as a view to the user. I also need to send to user the same html text as an email (minus the top navigation bar).

My thought was to put the payment details in a partial view. I can then use this partial view on the website as well as in the email.

In appears `Html` object is injected into razor pages automatically such that one can, for example, call `@Html.Partial().` Is there a way to use this `Html` object from the Controller class? Or, is there a different mechanism to render `.cshtml` file into html string? Regards.

Comment: You can send html string to View using Viewbag and there you want to display html right use Html.Raw("Put your html content in this").

Comment: @Saineshwar, He want the rendered string in his own C# code to use in mailing system

Comment: Possible duplicate of [return View as String in .NET CORE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40912375/return-view-as-string-in-net-core)

Answer (score 0):

You might try Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.HtmlString or Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.HtmlFormattableString. You can return these directly from the controller.