# .NET Core 2.1 - Execute ControllerB.Action from ControllerA.Action returning a String

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a system that generates emails. The content of parts of these emails is derived from ParialViews. 
In my EmailController I want to be able to obtain the HTML snippet(s) that form areas of the email template by calling their relevant actions and inserting the View HTML.

I've seen the post(s) here ([Return View as String in .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40912375/return-view-as-string-in-net-core)) regarding it but it doesn't quite work...

The solution below does find and attempt to get the View HTML *but* it doesn't actually attempt to execute the View's controller action. 
As the View is dynamic this results in an error.

So, can I **execute** `ControllerB.Action` retruning it's result as a string from within `ControllerA.Action`?

My current attempt: 
**The Service:**

```
public interface IViewRenderService
    {
        Task<string> RenderToStringAsync(string viewName, object model);
    }

    public class ViewRenderService : IViewRenderService
    {
        private readonly IRazorViewEngine _razorViewEngine;
        private readonly ITempDataProvider _tempDataProvider;
        private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

        public ViewRenderService(IRazorViewEngine razorViewEngine,
            ITempDataProvider tempDataProvider,
            IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            _razorViewEngine = razorViewEngine;
            _tempDataProvider = tempDataProvider;
            _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        }

        public async Task<string> RenderToStringAsync(string viewName, object model)
        {
            var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext { RequestServices = _serviceProvider };
            var actionContext = new ActionContext(httpContext, new RouteData(), new ActionDescriptor());

            using (var sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                var viewResult = _razorViewEngine.FindView(actionContext, viewName, false);

                if (viewResult.View == null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException($"{viewName} does not match any available view");
                }

                var viewDictionary = new ViewDataDictionary(new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(), new ModelStateDictionary())
                {
                    Model = model
                };

                var viewContext = new ViewContext(
                    actionContext,
                    viewResult.View,
                    viewDictionary,
                    new TempDataDictionary(actionContext.HttpContext, _tempDataProvider),
                    sw,
                    new HtmlHelperOptions()
                );

                await viewResult.View.RenderAsync(viewContext);
                return sw.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

**Starup.cs**
`services.AddScoped<IViewRenderService, ViewRenderService>();`

**Controller A**

```
private readonly IViewRenderService _viewRenderService;
public ReportController(...
        IViewRenderService viewRenderService)
{
    ...
    _viewRenderService = viewRenderService;
}
```

**The call from Controller A:**
`var theHtmlString = await _viewRenderService.RenderToStringAsync("ControllerB/Action1", new { parameters = paramsmodel });`

Comment: That's not how controllers work. If you want some shared functionality, create a regular (private/protected) method (no controller action) which you call in both controller actions

Comment: @Tseng cheers...I was thinking this would be the way. I have a bit of refactoring to do I think!