# How to get value/data of each element of List<Object>

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core

How to get value of Object from List in jQuery? Ath the moment I'm getting List of ActionResults from controller and I want to get value of each action (html code).

There is't a problem when I try to send single ActionResult - without list.

When I try to send `List<ActionResult>` I get `object Object` every time.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('click', 'button', function () {
        $cartAction = $("#" + this.id);
        var url = $cartAction.data("url");
        $.get(url, function (actions) {
           console.log(actions); <-- return Objects Array
           console.log(???); <-- how to get value of each actions
           console.log(actions[1]); <-- return a single object
           console.log(actions[1].document) <-- value undefined
        });
    });
</script>
```

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var actionList = new List<ActionResult>()
    {
        // ViewComponents, PartialViews
    };
    return Json(actionList);
}
```

I expect return html code for each ActionResult, but I get

> [object Object],[object Object]

for actions list.

**Edit:** Answer on my question is here [stackoverflow.com/a/53639387/10338470](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53639387/10338470)

Comment: Loop over the `actions` array. Don't use `alert` for debugging. Log to console and you will see exactly what you are working with

Comment: Do not return `List<ActionResult>` from action. Return `ActionResult` and at the end of method call `return Json(collection)`. In js browse object properties

Comment: After change on Json(collection) result is the same - undefined value

Comment: Maybe there's no document key in index 1? Does `actions.forEach(action => {console.dir(action);})` gives you any results?

Comment: I tried foreach loop and for every elements of list I get `Object` in console, but I want to get value this `Object` (html code)

Comment: In this case, `actions` is not a valid array of objects. Before the return statement add `string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(actionList);`, then log it `Console.WriteLine(json);` and check if it is valid.

Comment: I checked it and `json` was a string with `Object` elements like Arguments, Model etc.

Comment: So, what If you return the `json` string instead of `Json(actionList)` and use `JSON.parse(actions)` in JS? Would that work?

Comment: No, I want to get html code of ViewComponent, PartialView etc., no html code of object arguments.

Comment: Answer on my question is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/53639387/10338470

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery you can iterate through the Values like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('click', 'button', function () {
        $cartAction = $("#" + this.id);
        var url = $cartAction.data("url");
        $.get(url, function (actions) {
           console.log(actions); // <-- return Objects Array
           $.each(function() { // <-- iterates through each object in actions array
               console.log($(this)); // <-- logs the object to the console
           });
           console.log(actions[1]); // <-- return a single object
           console.log(actions[1].document) // <-- value undefined
        });
    });
</script>
```

In most browsers even `console.log(actions);` would work. But you can always `JSON.stringify(actions);`