# What options do we have to generate a PDF from an ASP.NET Core Web Api

Tags: asp.net, pdf

I need to generate a PDF from a HTML Canvas, but the process must complete on the server side which is an ASP.NET Core Web Api.

Comment: there aren't any built-in option/feature in `ASP.NET` to generate PDF. You either have to use a Server-Side library like [ItextSharp](https://itextpdf.com/en) or use a Client-Side library like [jsPDF](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf) or some tutorials like [Convert HTML table to PDF using pdfmake](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Convert-Export-HTML-Table-to-PDF-file-using-JavaScript.aspx) or any of your choice.

Comment: There is a good library aspos to do conversion on the server side. However it will be paid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using IronPdf;
IronPdf.HtmlToPdf Renderer = new IronPdf.HtmlToPdf();
// Render an HTML document or snippet as a string
Renderer.RenderHtmlAsPdf("<h1>Hello World</h1>").SaveAs("html-string.pdf");
// Advanced: 
// Set a "base url" or file path so that images, javascript and CSS can be loaded  
var PDF = Renderer.RenderHtmlAsPdf("<img src='icons/iron.png'>",@"C:\site\assets\");
PDF.SaveAs("html-with-assets.pdf");
```

[IronPDF for .NET Core](https://ironpdf.com/technology/dot-net-core/)

Comment: IronPdf requires paid licensing.

Answer (score 7):

On the server-side, you can output `HTML` of a view as `string` and can use any library that generate PDF from `HTML` `string`.
to render a view into `string` see this link [Return View as String in .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40912375/return-view-as-string-in-net-core)
after you got `HTML`, you need to pass it to the library see this link to convert `HTML` to `string`
[Convert HTML to PDF in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564650/convert-html-to-pdf-in-net)

1 Create a C# extension method to render view to string

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CC.Web.Helpers
{
    public static class ControllerExtensions
    {
        public static async Task<string> RenderViewAsync<TModel>(this Controller controller, string viewName, TModel model, bool partial = false)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
            {
                viewName = controller.ControllerContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;
            }

            controller.ViewData.Model = model;

            using (var writer = new StringWriter())
            {
                IViewEngine viewEngine = controller.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(ICompositeViewEngine)) as ICompositeViewEngine;
                ViewEngineResult viewResult = viewEngine.FindView(controller.ControllerContext, viewName, !partial);

                if (viewResult.Success == false)
                {
                    return $"A view with the name {viewName} could not be found";
                }

                ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(
                controller.ControllerContext,
                viewResult.View,
                controller.ViewData,
                controller.TempData,
                writer,
                new HtmlHelperOptions()
            );

                await viewResult.View.RenderAsync(viewContext);

                return writer.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2) Render view to string

```
viewHtml = await this.RenderViewAsync("Report", model);
```

3) Use HTML to create PDF

```
    Byte[] res = null;
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var pdf = TheArtOfDev.HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp.PdfGenerator.GeneratePdf(viewHtml, PdfSharp.PageSize.A4);
        pdf.Save(ms);
        res = ms.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: Thankyou so much for taking time and mentioning the best combination after so much research. I also after doing a lot of research found that you took the best possible combinations of all the steps and combined it in a single answer. Thankyou again for your hardwork

Comment: PdfSharp doesnt support .net core though?

Comment: Steps 1 & 2 can be simplified with this ready to use nuget package https://github.com/soundaranbu/RazorTemplating