# Download directly the view returned from controller in ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

Upon filling a form, and clicking download button it calls the following controller.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> InvigilatorDiaryPrint(InvigilatorDiaryDTO invigilatorDiaryDTO)
{
    var status = this._invigilatorDiaryService.CreateInvigilatorDiaryEntry(invigilatorDiaryDTO);

    if (invigilatorDiaryDTO.StudentDetails.Count == 0 && status)
    {
        invigilatorDiaryDTO = await this._invigilatorDiaryService.GetStudentEntryDetails(invigilatorDiaryDTO);
    }

    return this.View("~/Views/InvigilatorDiary/InvigilatorDiaryPrint.cshtml", invigilatorDiaryDTO);
}
```

This is a view different from where the current download button is placed. But on clicking download it should directly download the view returned from this controller as a pdf file instead of displaying it. How can I do that in ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What options do we have to generate a PDF from an ASP.NET Core Web Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58132155/what-options-do-we-have-to-generate-a-pdf-from-an-asp-net-core-web-api)

Comment: *"download the view"* and *"as a pdf"* are two very different things.

Comment: You need convert the view to pdf and then download it, refer to [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74204693/11398810).