# Return View as String in .NET Core - code redundancy

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr

This is a followup to [Return View as String in .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40912375/return-view-as-string-in-net-core). I'm working with the accepted answer (but most of them boil down to the same logic). Imagine some action on a controller `MyController`:

```
public async Task<PartialViewResult> Foo(int a, int b) 
{
 MyClass obj = await SomeQueryToDb(a, b);
 return PartialView("Foo", obj);
}
```

In context of SignalR hub I can return the view as:

```
public async Task<object> Foo(int a, int b) 
{
 MyClass obj = await SomeQueryToDb(a, b);
 return new {data = await service.RenderToStringAsync("~/Views/MyController/Foo.cshtml", obj, context.GetHttpContext())};
}
```

So on client side I can call Foo with SignalR, instead of opening XHR / fetch request which is faster.

The problem here is that `MyClass obj = await SomeQueryToDb(a, b);` is duplicated. Eg when I'm building a model for the view I'd have to keep the same code in two places. This could be fixed to some extent if I'd pass just the parameters as model (`Tuple<int, int>` in this case) and fetched actual data in view or in some class:

```
// Controller
public async Task<ActionResult> Foo(int a, int b) 
{
 return PartialView("Foo", await new MiddlewareMyController().BuildFoo(a, b));
}  

// Hub
public async Task<object> Foo(int a, int b) 
{
 return new {data = await service.RenderToStringAsync("~/Views/MyController/Foo.cshtml", await new MiddlewareMyController().BuildFoo(a, b), context.GetHttpContext())};
}
```

But again if I'd need to pass an additional parameter `c` I'd need to do that in two places. Also instancing class in this manner would take some memory.

The action on the controller must be requestable with direct URL request - eg: `somesite.com/mycontroller/foo?a=0&b=0`

My question is - how could I minimize code redundancy and make this easy to maintain? I'm using NET 5 RC1.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so first thing first about the instation it happens on every request. You can use the DI to create singletons but generally its not recommended in a multithreaded enviroment like you app. Now on the issues:

- Use an object as Paramater instead of `int a, int b` thus you can change the object and both will change. Having an object also allows you to automaticly validate the input using attributes.

  ```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Foo(QueryObject query)
    public async Task<ActionResult> FooHub(QueryObject query)
  ```
- Create a new method called `FooBuilder` or whatever you want which will handle the instantiation this mean that one method will  have the logic. Both of your methods will simply call this "builder"

  ```
   public async Task<ActionResult> Foo(QueryObject query)
   { 
     var foo = await FooBuilder(query);
   }

   public async Task<ActionResult> FooHub(QueryObject query)
   {
     var foo = await FooBuilder(query);
   }
   // Change dynamic to your object type
   public async dynamic FooBuilder(QueryObject query)
   {
     return await new MiddlewareMyController().BuildFoo(a, b)
   }
  ```
- Use DI to inject the middleware to the constructor and not on your controllers.

You will always instantiate in each and every request your service layer. You can use singletons but still what is your use case? It already weird that use Middleware to build something from the controller, it should be something like a service which holds the business logic.

Comment: how could I minimize code redundancy and make this easy to maintain? Code redudancy is writing the same information multiple times and as you pointed out how hard it is to make changes in multiple places. As this is an example and the first piece is different that the second one this is the way to do it for both a hub lets say for signal r and a normal controller.