# Use ASP.NET Core's ViewEngine to generate HTML outside Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'd want to generate html of `myview.cshtml` while passing string `test` to it

pseudo code based of `return View("myview", "test");`

`var html = View("myview", "test")`

I found a few working fine solutions to it, but they're limited to being executed in context of `Controller`

[Where are the ControllerContext and ViewEngines properties in MVC 6 Controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31905624/where-are-the-controllercontext-and-viewengines-properties-in-mvc-6-controller/31906578#31906578)

```
public static class ControllerExtensions
{
    public static async Task<string> RenderViewAsync<TModel>(this Controller controller, string viewName, TModel model, bool partial = false)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
        {
            viewName = controller.ControllerContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;
        }

        controller.ViewData.Model = model;

        using (var writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            IViewEngine viewEngine = controller.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(ICompositeViewEngine)) as ICompositeViewEngine;
            ViewEngineResult viewResult = viewEngine.FindView(controller.ControllerContext, viewName, !partial);

            if (viewResult.Success == false)
            {
                return $"A view with the name {viewName} could not be found";
            }

            ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(
                controller.ControllerContext,
                viewResult.View,
                controller.ViewData,
                controller.TempData,
                writer,
                new HtmlHelperOptions()
            );

            await viewResult.View.RenderAsync(viewContext);

            return writer.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

But how can I achieve that when I don't have any controller? do I have to create fake one? I'd want to avoid it because it requires a lot of DI `magic` to create instance of Controller

Comment: The normal Razor engine requires a view context and there is no way around it. If you want to render arbitrary Razor views to text, I would recommend you to use a library like [RazorLight](https://github.com/toddams/RazorLight).

Answer (score 2):

I have struggled to find a good answer to this for a while, and this is what I've come up with. **Note that this assumes that the code is being executed as part of a HTTP request, just not in the controller.** In my case, I know the calls to RenderViewAsync() will only come via a few controller methods, so I created a custom attribute that will store the controller instance in the HttpContext. You could, alternatively, write a filter or custom middleware to do this globally.

```
public class StoreControllerContextAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var controller = (Controller)context.Controller;

        context.HttpContext.Items.Add("Controller", controller);
    }
}
```

Decorate the relevant controller methods with this attribute:

```
[StoreControllerContext]
public async Task<IActionResult> ControllerMethod()
```

I put my RenderViewAsync() method in a service class, which gets passed an IHttpContextAccessor via DI.

```
public class RenderService
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public RenderService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public async Task<string> RenderViewAsync<TModel>(string viewName, TModel model, bool partial = false)
    {
        // Get the HttpContext using the accessor
        var httpContext = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
        // The controller should have been put into HttpContext.Items by the [StoreControllerContext] attribute on the controller method
        var controller = (Controller)(httpContext.Items["Controller"]);
        controller.ViewData.Model = model;

        using (var writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            IViewEngine viewEngine = httpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(ICompositeViewEngine)) as ICompositeViewEngine;
            // Using an absolute path, so use GetView() not FindView()
            ViewEngineResult viewResult = viewEngine.GetView(viewName, viewName, !partial);

            var temp = viewResult.SearchedLocations;

            if (viewResult.Success == false)
            {
                return $"A view with the name {viewName} could not be found";
            }

            ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(
                controller.ControllerContext,
                viewResult.View,
                controller.ViewData,
                controller.TempData,
                writer,
                new HtmlHelperOptions()
            );

            await viewResult.View.RenderAsync(viewContext);

            return writer.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

In Startup.cs you will need to register the service:

```
services.AddScoped<RenderService>();
```

and also ensure you enable the HttpContextAccessor:

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

Then I inject my RenderService where it is required, and call it like so:

```
string html = await _renderService.RenderViewAsync("~/Views/Path/To/MyView.cshtml", myModel, true);
```